# ValueError: "Unresolved named destination '_PAGE1'"error in PyPDF2

Tags: python, valueerror, pypdf

I am trying to merge some `.pdf` files in sub-folders

```
dir_name = r"E:\Data"    

        
import os, PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
#hdir=r #path to the folder directory; would suggest using os.getcwd()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dir_name):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for dir in dirs:
        sub_dir = os.path.join(root, dir)
        print(sub_dir)
        for filename in os.listdir(sub_dir):
            print(filename)
            if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
                filepath = os.path.join(sub_dir, filename)
                #print(filepath)
                merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filepath, 'rb')))
                #merger.write(str(filename))
        merger.write(os.path.join(dir_name,dir+'.pdf'))
```

code runs as expected for some sub-folders. But it is giving error as -
`ValueError: Unresolved named destination '_PAGE1'`.
Help me to solve this issue?
Traceback of error

````
  File "<ipython-input-5-bd9240b14192>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/Data/xxx.py', wdir='E:/Data')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "E:/Data/xxx.py", line 23, in <module>
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filepath, 'rb')))

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 174, in merge
    self._associate_dests_to_pages(srcpages)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 436, in _associate_dests_to_pages
    raise ValueError("Unresolved named destination '%s'" % (nd['/Title'],))

ValueError: Unresolved named destination '_PAGE1'```
````

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. I have added the traceback.

Comment: Which version of PyPDF2 did you use? Can you share the pdf? can you try again with the most recent version of pypdf?